# Is it possible to use Kafka Streams Windowing for no Aggreagate operator?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to use the Windowing mechanism that Kafka Streams provides in order to perform some actions on streaming data.
I've tried to simulate the windowing mechanism using `Processor API` to perform this action every n-seconds using `context.schedule()` but in this way I cannot have hopping windows.
Is there a way to achive this?
If I use the time interval in the `context.schedule()` for the advance of the window, then how can I controll/set the window size?

---

I need to keep a `StateStore` to hold a data structure through windows, then based on the content of this data structure I perform some modification of it based on the records that arrive. I need to perform this actions on every record that arrive, so I think I can use the `trasform` method. 
Finally at the end of each window I need to forward some data from the data structure that I mention before.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you really want to do. Can you edit your question providing more details? Why can't you use punctuations (your interval would of course need to be the window advance -- not the window size)?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thank you for your suggestion, I've added some information, it should be clearer now